# Adding 0-s to a list of until it's length is 8 in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, binary

So I have to make a decimal number into binary list like so: intToBitString 4 = [1,0,0].
Which i have done like so:

```
intToBitString n = reverse (helper n)

helper 0 = []
helper n 
        | n `mod` 2 == 1 = 1 : helper (n `div` 2) 
        | n `mod` 2 == 0 = 0 : helper(n `div` 2)
```

But then I also have to make a function called intToByte, which pads out the list with 0-s until it's length is 8 elements long. (so making it a bytestring) Like this: 
intToByte 7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

I have tried so many things, but they never work. I am a beginner, so I only know the "if" loop the way I showed above, and recursion, but I dont know anything fancy. One of my tries:

```
intToByte 0 = [0]

intToByte n
        | eight n == helper2 n = reverse (helper2 n)
        | otherwise = eight n

helper2 0 = []
helper2 n 
        | n `mod` 2 == 1 = 1 : helper2 (n `div` 2) 
        | n `mod` 2 == 0 = 0 : helper2 (n `div` 2)

eight n
        | length (helper2 n) < 8 = 0 : eight n
        | otherwise = helper2 n
```

I have been working on this for so many hours that i'm getting confused by it. But this is part of an important assignment, so help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding can be as simple as computing how many additional elements to push to the list and then have those elements produced using the function `replicate` from the Prelude:

```
padLeft :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
padLeft n x xs = replicate (n - length xs) x ++ xs
```

For instance:

```
> padLeft 8 0 [1, 1, 0]
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can simplify your code with:

```
helper2 :: Integral i => i -> [i]
helper2 0 = []
helper2 n = r : helper2 q
    where (q,r) = quotRem n 2
```

Secondly, the above is a [*big endian* representation [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Indeed, `7` is represented as `[1,1,1]`, whereas `14` is for example represented as `[0,1,1,1]`. If we want to revers this, we can work with an accumulator:

```
helper2 :: Integral i => i -> [i]
helper2 = go []
    where go rs 0 = rs
          go rs n = go (r:rs) q
              where (q,r) = quotRem n 2
```

This thus maps `7` to `[1,1,1]` and `14` to `[1,1,1,0]`. But now we still need to add leading zeros. We can do that for example by maintaing the number of elements already added to the list:

```
eight :: Integral i => i -> [i]
eight = go [] 0
    where go rs l 0 = replicate (8-l) 0 ++ rs
          go rs l n = go (r:rs) (l+1) q
              where (q,r) = quotRem n 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to define a function `bits` such that `bits k` converts its argument to a bit string of length `k`:

```
bits :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
bits 0 _n = []
bits k n | n < 0         = error "bits: negative"
         | n > 2 * m - 1 = error "bits: overflow"
         | otherwise     = let (i, j) = n `divMod` m in i : bits (k - 1) j
  where m = 2 ^ (k - 1)
```

Your function `eight` is then easily written as

```
eight :: Int -> [Int]
eight = bits 8
```

This gives:

```
> eight 4
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]

> eight 7
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Your `m` calculation is rather inefficient. Why not pass `m` *instead* of `k`?

Comment: Also, you can handle the error conditions in a wrapper. It's also reasonable not to consider them (especially overflow) errors.